# How to draw a hexagonal pyramid in latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, pstricks, asymptote, metapost

I am trying to draw a hexagonal pyramid in latex like the one below? 
[image]

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: You probably want a tikz/pgf 3-D plot.

Comment: PSTricks also has an awesome 3D plot package called `pst-solides3d`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are rarely answered. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.
This question will be very likely closed in a short time. Addition of a MWE might contribute to its reopening

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A solution that allows you to switch on the perspective view, if needed.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{perspective}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[3d view={55}{20},declare function={a=2;b=3;l=5;},
    %perspective,
    >=stealth,line cap=round,line join=round]
 \draw[->]  (tpp cs:x=0,y=0,z=0) coordinate (O) -- (tpp cs:x=l,y=0,z=0);
 \draw[->]  (O) -- (tpp cs:x=0,y=l,z=0);
 \draw[->]  (tpp cs:x=0,y=0,z=b) -- (tpp cs:x=0,y=0,z=l);
 \path foreach \X in {1,...,6}
  {(tpp cs:x={a*cos(\X*60-30)},y={a*sin(\X*60-30)},z=0) coordinate (p\X)}
  (tpp cs:x=0,y=0,z=b) coordinate (tip);
 \draw[fill=white] plot[samples at={1,...,6}] (p\x) -- cycle;
 \draw foreach \X in {1,...,6} {(p\X) edge (tip)};
 \draw[dashed] foreach \X in {1,2,3} {(p\X) edge (p\the\numexpr\X+3)}
  (O) edge (tip);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you uncomment `perspective`, you get

[image]

The details about this view can be found in section **64 Three Point Perspective Drawing Library** of pgfmanual v3.1.5.

You can change the view angles, of course.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{perspective}
\begin{document}
\foreach \X in {5,15,...,355}
{\begin{tikzpicture}
 \path[use as bounding box](-6,-3) rectangle (6,6);
 \begin{scope}[3d view={\X}{20+10*sin(\X)},declare function={a=2;b=3;l=5;},
    >=stealth,line cap=round,line join=round]
  \draw[->]  (tpp cs:x=0,y=0,z=0) coordinate (O) -- (tpp cs:x=l,y=0,z=0);
  \draw[->]  (O) -- (tpp cs:x=0,y=l,z=0);
  \draw[->]  (tpp cs:x=0,y=0,z=b) -- (tpp cs:x=0,y=0,z=l);
  \path foreach \X in {1,...,6}
   {(tpp cs:x={a*cos(\X*60-30)},y={a*sin(\X*60-30)},z=0) coordinate (p\X)}
   (tpp cs:x=0,y=0,z=b) coordinate (tip);
  \draw[fill=white] plot[samples at={1,...,6}] (p\x) -- cycle;
  \draw foreach \X in {1,...,6} {(p\X) edge (tip)};
  \draw[dashed] foreach \X in {1,2,3} {(p\X) edge (p\the\numexpr\X+3)}
   (O) edge (tip);
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 I guessed you upvoted my answer.

Comment: @MoneyOrientedProgrammer Yes, I did (even though this will unlikely give you more money. ;-)

Comment: I am always amazed with your full time (24/7) voluntarily support here. There must be a passive income. :-)

Comment: @MoneyOrientedProgrammer I am a sociologists, and some individuals with remarkable personality structure hang out on this site. So I have free access to very interesting patterns of behavior. ;-)

Answer (score 8):

A PSTricks solution just for fun purpose. Compile it with 3 steps:

- `latex mop.tex`
- `dvips mop.dvi`
- `ps2pdf mop.ps`

```
% this file name is mop.tex
\documentclass[pstricks,border=0pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-5,0)(5,11)
    \pstGeonode[PosAngle={180,-90,-90,0,45,135,90}]
        (-4,3){A}
        (-2,1){B}
        (1,1){C}
        (4,3){D}
        (2,5){E}
        (-1,5){F}
        (1,10){T}
    \foreach \i in {A,B,C,D}{\psline(T)(\i)}
    \foreach \i in {A,E,T}{\psline[linestyle=dashed](F)(\i)}
    \foreach \i in {D,T}{\psline[linestyle=dashed](E)(\i)}
    \psline(A)(B)(C)(D)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Other parts are intentionally left for your typing exercises!

You can also compile it with a single step with `xelatex mop.tex`. Unfortunately, this method takes a huge amount of time to compile.

Answer (score 6):

My humble attempt for MetaPost. Although I've used the embedded library of LuaTeX (via ConTeXt), you can include it in LaTeX using packages such as [`gmp`](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/gmp/gmp.pdf) or directly saving the code in a `.mp` file and compiling via `mpost` so you include your output using `\includegraphics...` or any similar.

```
\startTEXpage
\startMPcode
%Save in figure.mp and use "mpost figure.mp"
%Uncomment the following lines in the standalone file
%prologues := 3;
%beginfig(1)
u := 1cm;
pair p[]; 
for i = 1 upto 6:
    p[i] := dir(60*i-30) xscaled 2 rotated 10 scaled u;
endfor
pair q, r;
q := origin;
r := (0,4)*u;
draw p1
for i = 2 upto 6:
    --p[i]
endfor
--cycle;
for i = 1 upto 6:
    draw q -- p[i] dashed evenly;
    draw r -- p[i];
endfor
draw q -- r dashed evenly;
drawarrow q -- 0.5[p5,p6] scaled 2;
drawarrow r -- (1.25*r);
drawarrow p1 -- (sqrt(3)*p1);
%endfig;
%end
\stopMPcode  
\stopTEXpage
```

[image]